# OpenGL doesn't consider distance of GL_DIFFUSE positional light

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting, light, opengl-compat

I want to put a positional light in my scene. I expect distant objects to take less light, but opengl just care about angle between surface normal and light. Am I doing something wrong or do I have to add another function?

```
GLfloat lightIntensity=1.0;
GLfloat main_position[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat light_ambient[] = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.0};
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = {lightIntensity, lightIntensity, lightIntensity, 1.0};
GLfloat light_specular[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

/* Enable a single OpenGL light. */
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, main_position);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

When I run the code, 2 object with same surface normal have same lighting even though they have different distance from the light source

Comment: For a distance dependent light you've to set the attenuation parameters `GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION` respectively `GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION`. See [`glLight`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLight.xml). By default the light is constant independent on the distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a distance dependent light you've to set the attenuation parameters `GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION`, `GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION` respectively `GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION`. See [`glLight`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glLight.xml). By default the light is constant independent on the distance.

The light attenuation is specified in [OpenGL 2.0  Specification - 2.14.1 Lighting](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec20.pdf#page=73&zoom=100,0,522), page 62.
The light attenuation factor is defiend as:

```non
att = 1 / (kc + kl * d + kq * d * d)

d  ... distance from the light source to the fragment
kc ... constant attenuation
kl ... linear attenuation
kq ... quadratic attenuation
```

The default value for the constant attenuation is 1, for the linear and quadratic attenuation it is 0. This leads to a distance independent factor of 1.

e.g. In the following a attenuation is set, where the attenuation factor is `<= 1.0/255.0` at a distance of `max_dist`:

```cpp
float max_dist = ...;
float threshold = 1.0f/255.0f;

float kc = 0.0f;
float kq = 0.0f;
float kl = (1.0f/threshold - kc - kq*max_dist*max_dist) / max_dist;

glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION,  kc);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION,    kl);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, kq);
```

For quadratic attenuation the same can be achieved by

```cpp
float kc = 0.0f;
float kl = 0.0f;
float kq = (1.0f/threshold - kc - kl*max_dist) / (max_dist*max_dist);
```